# Replacing css flex with tables

Tags: html, css, flexbox, email-templates

I'm using flex to display certain details on a report. But I found that email clients are not supporting it and I see it can be achieved with tables instead.

This is my code. How do I use tables to achieve the same results? Specifically how do we increase and decrease the cell widths, if we are going to use tables?

```css
    body {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    div {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .divtable {
        border-top: 1px solid #eceff1;
        margin: 0 -16px;
        word-break: break-all;
    }
    
    .tablerow {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eceff1;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .tablecol {
        line-height: 1.5em;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        flex: 1;
    }
    
    .bar {
        border-radius: 3px;
        background: #eee;
        display: inline-flex;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .text {
        display: inline-block;
        background: #04b;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
    
    .a {
        background: #28EB52;
    }
    .b {
        background: #F0FF0D;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="divtable">
        <div class="tablerow">
            <div class="tablecol">Label</div>
            <div class="tablecol">
                <div class="bar">
                    <div class="text a" style="flex-grow: 8">8</div>
                    <div class="text b" style="flex-grow: 15">15</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I did attempt using tables. I'm unable to get the width's right. Is there a better way of doing this?

`(8 / (8+15)) x 100 = 34.7%`
`(15 / (8+15)) x 100 = 65.3%`

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:25%">Label 1</th>
        <td style="text-align: center; background: #28EB52; width: 34.7%;">8</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; background: #F0FF0D; width: 65.3%;">15</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:25%">Label 2</th>
        <td style="text-align: center; background: #28EB52; width: 33.3%;">5</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; background: #F0FF0D; width: 33.3%;">5</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; background: #28EB52; width: 33.3%;">5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if you work with email-templates you should use inline-style as CSS is barely supported aswell.

Comment: HTML emails are now the only place where it is acceptable to use the table tag for layout. You will need to rely on inline styles as well. Be prepared for a **lot** of inconsistencies across email clients

Comment: Email coding is its own beast, where practically no modern HTML/CSS features are available. I'd suggest you check out overview resources provided by [MailChimp](https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/html-email-basics/), [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding-html-emails/), [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/04/complete-guide-html-email-templates-tools/), and the likes, so you have the fundamental limitations and guidelines to email coding. Also, consider using a tool like [MJML](https://mjml.io/) for dev productivity.

Comment: I attempted it using tables and have added my results about, but I'm still having problems with getting the widths right.